# Triple integral - wedge shaped solid

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

Find the volume of of the wedge shaped solid that lies above the xy plane, below the $z=x$ plane and within the cylinder $x^2+y^2 = 4$.

I'm having serious trouble picturing this. I think the z bounds are [0,x], but can't figure out any of the other ones.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
V & = \iiint_{\mathbb{R}^{\large 3}}\bracks{z > 0}
\bracks{z < x}\bracks{x^{2} + y^{2} < 4}\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bracks{0 < z < \rho\cos\pars{\phi}}
\bracks{\rho > 0}\bracks{\rho^{2} < 4}\rho\,\dd\rho\,\dd\phi
\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}
\int_{0}^{2}\bracks{0 < z < \rho\cos\pars{\phi}}
\rho\,\dd\rho\,\dd\phi\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
2\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}
\int_{0}^{2}\bracks{0 < z < -\rho\cos\pars{\phi}}
\rho\,\dd\rho\,\dd\phi\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
2\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\int_{0}^{2}\bracks{0 < z < \rho\sin\pars{\phi}}
\rho\,\dd\rho\,\dd\phi\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\int_{0}^{2}\rho\sin\pars{\phi}\rho\,\dd\rho\,\dd\phi =
2\pars{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin\pars{\phi}\,\dd\phi}
\pars{\int_{0}^{2}\rho^{2}\,\dd\rho}
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{16 \over 3}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

looks like this should be the required vol
$$2\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{rcos\theta}  rdzdrd\theta $$

Comment: why is it [$0,\frac{\pi}{2}$] and not [$\pi, 2\pi]$? The $d\theta$ bound is what I'm asking about, because I got all of the other ones. Also, why do you multiply by 2?

Comment: the region in xy plane, is of 1st and 4th quadrant, so $[\pi, 2\pi]$ doesn't look like being there.the volume is above 1st and 4th quadrant of xy plane, so you can adjust $d\theta$ accordingly.and since i chose $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ so multiplied by 2

Comment: $2\times$ is because of symmetry. Otherwise you'd have to integrate $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}$.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are describing a variation of the hoof of Archimedes (see figure below). If that's the case, I can give you a detailed solution and show you how to reduce the triple integral for volume to a single integration. From what you describe, the height would be $R$, rather than the $2R$ shown in the figure.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Planes $x={\rm const.}$ intersect this solid $B$ in rectangles of width $2\sqrt{4-x^2}$ and height $x$ (see the figure in Cye Waldman's answer). One therefore obtains
$${\rm vol}(B)=\int_0^2 2\sqrt{4-x^2}\>x\>dx=-{2\over3}(4-x^2)^{3/2}\biggr|_0^2={16\over3}\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

I'll try this with some custom techniques:

First we need expression for (x,y) -values which are inside the cylinder:
$$ C = \{ (x,y) | x^2+y^2<4 \} $$

Then we need expression for "bars" from xy-plane to z=x plane:

$$ [(x,y,0) .. (x,y,x)], (x,y) \in C $$

Then we need to calculate the length of the bar:
$$ \pi_1 : (x,y) \rightarrow (x), (x,y) \in C $$

Then we just cut out bars that are $<0$:
$$ F=\{ (x) | (x,y) \in C, x\ge0 \}$$

Then area of the circle is:
 $$ A = \frac{1}{2} \pi 2^2 $$

Then we should pick random point from C and calculate average:
$$ \int_{C,x\geq0}{x dC} = A \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{k}{F(x_n,y_n)}}{k}, k>10000$$, where $(x_n,y_n)$ are random point picked from $C$ so that $x\geq0$.

Picking the random point becomes possible with the following bounding box:
 $$ B = ([-2..2],[-2..2]) $$ and usage of $C$ to filter out the points that do not match $x^2+y^2<4$ condition.

The bounding box needs to be adjusted for $x\geq 0$: $$B=([0..2],[-2..2])$$.